# Pass QuerySet in Django url

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to pass a list as the queryset parameter to a Django ListView. I know you can do this by overwriting the `get_queryset` method but ideally I would like to avoid this. The reason is, I am referring from another view and already have the queryset I need so I don't want to run the same query twice.

Currently I am linking to my view as follows:

```
<a href="{url 'lab_work:project_list_ongoing' %}?projects={{active}}">{{active|length}</a>
```

`active` is the prepopulated list I want to use as the queryset.
My view looks as follows:

```
class ProjectListOngoing(ListView):
    template_name = "<name of my template>"
    model = Project
    context_object_name = "projects"
    paginate_by = 10
    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.projects = request.GET.get('projects', [])
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.projects
```

This does seem to populate the correct queryset however the primary keys are blank for some reason.

I have the following in my template:

```
{% for project in projects %}
   <li><a href="{% url 'lab_work:project_detail' pk=project.pk %}"></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

And I get the following error:

```
Reverse for 'project_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['project/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: Maybe you could use cached property on the model used for queryset? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional

Comment: @intelis Wouldn't that require some other model? I'm implementing a list view so they just list my queried `Project` model objects